# C++ Find file name before file extension

Tags: c++, filenames

I am new to C++ and learning curve has taught me a lot already, but now I really need to find a way to this quickly, and neatly.

I tried many ways, but can't figure it out (or it works; but partially).

```
size_t found = strFullPathName.find(".file001");

if (found != string::npos)
{
    //Find us the filename, and return in correct format.
    strFullPathName = strFullPathName.substr(0, strFullPathName.find(".file001"));
    strFullPathName = szCurDir + "\\output\\" + strFullPathName + ".file001";
}
```

The above code, gives me *anything* before the *.file001* extension.

But what I want in reality is just a way to fetch the **filename**.

This could be with or without extension, preferred without.

This can be done numerous ways, I'm sure. but i cant seem to find a easy and quick way to do it.

Thank you in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Get a filename is surprisingly hard with all the filesystems rules in place. Why don't you use std::filesystem::path and let it do the hard work?

Comment: Which C++? starting from 17 you have https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract just the file name, simply `rfind()` or `find_last_of()` the last `'/'` and/or `'\'` char in the string, depending on platform, and then `substr()` everything after it.

Then, to remove the extension, you can `rfind()` the last `'.'` char in the extracted file name, and then `substr()` everything before it.

```cpp
size_t found = strFullPathName.find_last_of("/\\");
if (found != string::npos)
{
    //Find us the filename, and return in correct format.
    strFullPathName = strFullPathName.substr(found+1);
    found = strFullPathName.rfind(".");
    if (found != string::npos)
        strFullPathName = strFullPathName.substr(0, found);
    strFullPathName = szCurDir + "\\output\\" + strFullPathName + ".file001";
}
```

Comment: This answer has worked for me, it's less elegant than the more useful answer stated above by @John Zwinck, but it's exactly what i need

Answer (score 5):

If you have C++17, use this:

```
std::filesystem::path(strFullPathName).stem()
```

That will give you the filename without the extension, and works on any platform supporting C++17.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/stem

If you do not have C++17 but are on a POSIX-style system like Linux or Mac OS, [`basename()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html) will give you the filename including the extension.

If you do not have C++17 and are on Windows, try [`_splitpath_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-s-wsplitpath-s?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I'm using C++ 2010, visual studio - forgot to mention im trying to save a file, not read one.